# Add new elements to mysql with html

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am trying to add new elements to my database on mysql through my webpage.

This is what I've got so far

```
<form action="MyCurrentPage.php" method="post" >
   <label for="playername"> Player </label>
   <input type="text" name="addplayer" id="playername"/>
   <input type= "submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and this

```
<?php
     if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $addplayerv=$_POST['addplayer'];
        $mysqli->select_db("player", $player);

        $sql="INSERT INTO player (nameofplayer) VALUES ('".$addplayerv."')";
        $mysqli->query($sql, $mysqli);
        $mysqli->close($mysqli);
     }

?>
```

The problem with this is that its not updating anything and I am not getting any errors.

Comment: you have not taken the name attribute in submit button

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: your database name and your table name is same ??

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
> ```

You only process the data if the form submits a control named `submit`.

You have no control with that name (the submit button has `submit` as the *type* and the *value* but it has no name).

Give the submit button a name.

Comment: I did that but now it gives me this errors: 

 Undefined variable: player (on the select_db line)

mysqli::select_db() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in

mysqli::query() expects parameter 2 to be integer, object given 

mysqli::close() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given

Comment: but "player" is the name of my database and the connection to mysql is fine, I dont know why I am getting that error.

Comment: @user12654809 — Yes, `"player"` in the name of the database. `$player` is an undefined variable used as a second argument to a function that only takes one argument in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Please add attribute name on Submit form. Because if you did not mentioned the name attribute, the data which you want to post for add is not entered into condition which you have written under the PHP tags.

Please change the HTML with this:

```
<form action="MyCurrentPage.php" method="post" >
<label for="playername"> Player </label>
<input type="text" name="addplayer" id="playername"/>
<input type= "submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

missing submit input name 
your input should be something like this

```
<input type= "submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
```

and your db connection your passing two parameters in select_db() that's wrong 
you have to pass one parameter.
should be like this

```
$player="player";

 $mysqli->select_db($player);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $addplayerv=$_POST['addplayer'];
        $mysqli->select_db("player");

        $sql="INSERT INTO player (nameofplayer) VALUES ('".$addplayerv."')";
        $mysqli->query($sql);
        $mysqli->close();
    }
?>
```

select_db() needs one parameter: the name of the database you're using.
query() only needs the sql query.
close() doesn't expect any parameter.